# How to call ASP.NET AJAX CascadingDropDown raiseSelectionChanged()

Tags: .net, asp.net, ajax, drop-down-menu

Anyone know how to do this?

This does not work: `$get("<%= cddToCompetition.ClientID %>").raiseSelectionChanged(null);`

I have two separate CascadingDropDown controls, where a change in control A should trigger a change in control B (the one in my example). Control A is not the parent of B.

Answer (score 1):

What if you add AsyncPostBackTrigger trigger

```
<Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="yourParentControldID" EventName="SelectedIndexChange" />        
</Triggers>
```

**Edit:**

```
document.getElementById('<%=yourDropdown.ClientId%>').onchange();
```

also check this thread [fire-dropdown-selectedindexchanged-event-in-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007190/want-to-fire-dropdown-selectedindexchanged-event-in-javascript)

Comment: I think that would only work in an UpdatePanel. Here, I have two separate CascadingDropDown controls, where a change in control A should trigger a change in control B. Control A is *not* the parent of B.

Comment: @Mark; ooh I misunderstood, now check my edit portion. Thanks